# How to change image of button in javaFX?

Tags: java, image, button, javafx

I am using javaFX.
I made a button and set an image for this . the code is :

```
    Image playI=new Image("file:///c:/Users/Farhad/Desktop/icons/play2.jpg");
    ImageView iv1=new ImageView(playI);
    iv1.setFitHeight(67);
    iv1.setFitWidth(69);

    Button playB=new Button("",iv1);
```

But i want to when i click the button , image changes to another picture.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set the buttons Graphic in an Action

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("play3.jpg"));
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        Button button = (Button) e.getSource();
        button.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
    }
});
```