# JavaFX: set an overlapping text on a button when clicked

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a simple lottery game where I can chose numbers from 1 to 42. I would like to mark the chosen number with a red "X" (instead of using an effect) but the user should still see the chosen number beneath the "X". When the user clicks the marked number again, the "X" should disappear.
The GUI looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Vgl.png)

How can I display a second text on a button in the way that the first text is still visible?

Thanks for your help

kind regards

Joel

Comment: Maybe make a background image with the red "X" and set the image like [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496107/7571258).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Graphic of a button to a StackPane and then add an element to the StackPane. Since the children of a StackPane are all displayed on top of each other, this yields the effect that you want. My example just shows the concept, I would probably write a new class that extends Button in your use scenario :)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        StackPane buttonPane = new StackPane();
        Label label = new Label("42");
        buttonPane.getChildren().add(label);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setGraphic(buttonPane);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(buttonPane.getChildren().size() == 1){
                    Label labelX = new Label("X");
                    labelX.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");
                    buttonPane.getChildren().add(labelX);
                }
                else 
                    buttonPane.getChildren().remove(1);
            }
        });

        pane.getChildren().addAll(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks. But now I got the next problem:

Comment: nice, no problem. Make sure to accept this answer then, so that others can find it :)

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks. But now I got the next problem: I've made an array for the 42 buttons and also an array for each button's StackPane. Normally each button has normal text ("1" to "42"). With (Button) event.getSource(); I can get this text, but now there is a StackPane with a label on the Button as a graphic, how can I get the text of the label in this situation? I tried several things but I don't get any text. I need the text to know which button is actually clicked. A solution would be to make an event for each button without a for loop...but thats ugly :D

Comment: I see. That is why I suggested using a class for your buttons, like: public class LottoButton extends Button{ /* your code here */ } this class would have a private String text, and getter and setter methods. And of course this StackPane-construct that we used before. That would be the proper OOP-way of doing it, and I'd strongly recommend that. A working, but really dirty way would be ((Label)((StackPane)button.getGraphic()).getChildren().get(0)).getText(); but don't do that :D